# Table Attribute binding not working when using IQueryable<T>

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure app function that i would like to read from an azure storage Table. I am new to azure functions and table storage. But can not get the samples to work properly.

the functions are created in visual Studio 2017 and published to azure.

The app function have 2 functions, 1 for posting and one for getting. 
The post functions work as expected.

The getter function fails with below error:

```
internal error 500: "'TableName' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?"
```

Get function:

```
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
    public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")]HttpRequestMessage req, [Table("TableName", Connection = "Default")]IQueryable<Person> inTable, TraceWriter log)
    {
       return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The only difference between the post and get methods is their signature.
the post sets the tableattribute for the ICollector interface.

```
[Table("TableName", Connection = "Default")]ICollector<Person> outTable
```

And the get sets the table attribute for the IQueryable Interface

```
[Table("TableName", Connection = "Default")]IQueryable<Person> inTable
```

Any input is appreciated.

This is almost the default sample provided for working with table storage.

Comment: In your post you have the table name specified as “AssetAdressBook” and for get you have “TableName”. Is there really s table called “TableName” or would this work if replaced with “AssetAdressBook” too ?

Comment: Oh, forgot to edit that. They are identical in my code.

Answer (score 0):

When using IQueryable, the T must implement ITableEntity (or derive from TableEntity) from the Storage SDK. ICollector does not have this constraint.

Be sure to use the same version of the storage SDK  that the your project already has from its Microsot.NET.SDK.Functions reference (and not pull in a new, different storage SDK that loads side-by-side).

There are some more details here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table, although those examples are *.CSX (where the bindings are in a separate function.json file) and 
not *.cs (where the bindings are inline attributes). But the C# types and rules are the same.

Comment: The person class is implemented ITableEntity. I'll check out the references. Thanks